# Composite Index or Single Index on column

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, indexing

I have a table with more than 1M rows.

Currently, it contains a composite **Index**: (**Code**, **UserIdentifier**). Searches using these two columns are very common, so this composite index makes sense.

I also need to be able to search the following: `WHERE Code = 'someCode' AND Name LIKE 'ABC%'`.
The **Name** column will always be searched with the "%" **after the search term**.

I assume simply adding a INDEX on **Name**, would mean that when the SELECT is performed, the engine **will use the composite index** (**Code**, **UserIdentifier**) to first filter by Code and then use the **index** on **Name**, to filter based on the LIKE clause.
The other case would be to add besides the existing composite index, another **composite index** composed of both (**Code**, **Name**), I assume would be faster. However, I worry that since the Code column would in this case be part of both the composite indexes, it might lower performance overall.

Which of the following indexes would make most sense here, and would be the fastest,
considering the fact that there **already exists** a composite index for the columns (`Code`, `UserIdentifier`):

1. INDEX (`Name`)
2. INDEX (`Code`, `Name`)
3. INDEX (`Name`, `Code`)

Thank you!

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: `INDEX (Code, Name)` make sense for you query

Comment: Edited the question, it was a LIKE operator.

Comment: Note that your query will only use one of the indexes. (I.e. your "first this index, then that index" assumption is wrong.)

Comment: Since we don't know the data distribution, and constraints, we can't know which index to choose.

Comment: The reasonability of additional index creation depends on the data statistic. How many rows are stored in the table? What is average/approximate output rows amount for `WHERE Code = 'someCode'` and for `WHERE Code = 'someCode' AND Name LIKE 'ABC%'` queries? It is possible that existing index modifying to `(Code, UserIdentifier, Name)` will be more reasonable than `(Code, Name)` index creation.

Comment: @Akina - No.  The Optimizer would stop at `UserIdentifier` and not really get to `Name`.

Comment: @RickJames Not correct. The server will use index seek by `Code` and index scan by `Name`. This is more fast than seeking by `Code` with further table scan. So such index will improve. And, if the amount of rows which matches the condition by `Code` is small enough then the total improvement may be high enough.

Comment: @Akina - The 'key' for the index is essentially the concatenation of the 3 columns.  Then searching for `code` and `name` when having only `INDEX(code, x, name)` is like doing `LIKE 'code%name'`  With that said, I guess we "agree to disagree".

Comment: @RickJames *Then searching for code and name when having only INDEX(code, x, name) is like doing LIKE 'code%name'*. ?? For index `(code, x)` - server seeks by `code`, then extracts and scans by `name` from the table body. For index `(code, x, name)` - server seeks by `code`, then extracts and scans by `name` from the index, it does not need to access the table, and this is obviously more fast. This is similar to covering index usage.

Comment: @Akina - Sure.  That's "covering".  But it is still less optimal than `(code, name, ...)`.  I like to first optimize the index _without_ considering "covering", _then_ see if it makes sense to add on other columns.

Answer (score 1):

The comment from Ergest Basha above is correct. The index on `(Code, Name)` is most likely to be helpful.

There is no problem making two indexes with the same first column. They may both be useful for different queries, and it's worth the extra storage for the two indexes.

You should use [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/explain.html) to analyze how queries use indexes. No need to ask here on Stack Overflow, you should test it for yourself.

MySQL usually uses only one index per table reference in a given query (there is an "[index merge optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/index-merge-optimization.html)" but it doesn't kick in as often as you might think).

You might like my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really) or the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU).

Comment: If there are only a few different code values, but hundreds of different names, I'd go with (name, code) instead. Or perhaps code has a unique constraint...

Comment: @jarlh, No, because in the OP's example query their condition on `name` is a range condition. If you put the `name` column first in the index, then the query won't use the second column of the index. Columns used in equality conditions must go first.